# What Goes in the index.html file?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am building one of my first applications using Sencha Touch 2, and I could not find on the net what to link exactly in the index.html as I am following a tutorial on the net and I am  receiving a blank screen (The Problem is from the index file). I would love some help about it as like I said, I couldn't find anything on the internet.

```
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="touch/microloader/development.js"></script>
<script src="../touch-2.1.1/sencha-touch-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../touch-2.1.1/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And I Already Use Sencha Cmd to generate my applications. The Browser I use is Chrome Version 24.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your index.html, show us the errors you get in the web inspector.

Comment: Agreed, show us your index file. That said, you may want to look at [Sencha Cmd](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/) as a way to generate your app structure (including the index.html file).

Comment: I Already Use Sencha Cmd to generate my application

Answer (score 3):

Firstly if you are starting you should not write files on your own, you should generate project using Sencha Cmd. Here are details:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command_app

and if you want to learn what to do after that you should go through this brilliant tutorial http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/

Still you get blank page please show index.html file.

BTW which browser you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the problem was in the code and not in the index file as I did not reference correctly a file.

Thanks :)